# How to prove the sequence of function converge pointwise to a continuous function?

Tags: calculus

Let $f_n(x), n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$ denote the sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ defined by $$f_0 = 1,  f_n(x) = \sqrt{x f_{n-1}(x)}$$

Prove that the sequenc converges pointwise to a continuous function and the convergence is uniform.

The sequence should be {$1,x^{1/2},x^{3/4}, x^{7/8},  ... $}. It's obvious it point wise to some continuous function that grows very fast, but I don't know how to prove it. Also I couldn't find the function to which it point wise continued. Hence I don't know how to prove it converges uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \ge 1$,

$$f_n(x) = x^{1/2}f_{n-1}^{1/2}(x) = x^{1/2}x^{1/4}f_{n-2}^{1/4}(x) = \cdots = x^{1/2}x^{1/4}\cdots x^{1/2^n}f_0^{1/2^n}(x) = x^{1 - 1/2^n}.$$

So $\{f_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a monotone sequence of nonnegative continuous functions on the compact interval $[0,1]$ that is pointwise convergent to $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$. By Dini's theorem, $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.